# Should I pause my thread or not Android

Tags: android

So I have thread where it checks every 10ms's if drag is almost outside draggingzone. Basicly my thread code is doing nothing 99% of time so should I make it to pause and resume only when needed? Or does this literally do nothing when right and left are false?

My code looks like this

```
 timer = new Thread() { //new thread
        public void run() {
            b = true;
            try {
                do {
                    sleep(10);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (right) {
                                dragzone.moveleft(-5);
                            } else if (left) {
                                dragzone.moveleft(5);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                while (b);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }

        ;
    };
    timer.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like using a Thread here is not necessary, and you should switch to using a Handler and [`postDelayed()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long))

First, declare your Handler, boolean, and a Runnable as instance variables:

```
Handler handler;
boolean b;

Runnable checkDragZone = new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (right) {
            dragzone.moveleft(-5);
        } else if (left) {
            dragzone.moveleft(5);
        }

        if (b){
            handler.postDelayed(this, 10);
        }

    }
};
```

To start monitoring, set `b` to true, and start the Runnable:

```
    handler = new Handler();
    b = true;
    handler.postDelayed(checkDragZone, 10);
```

To stop it (temporarily or permanently), just set `b` to false:

```
    b = false;
```

Comment: This is working almost as good at It should be. But after many drag events there will be lots of handlers running at same time. Because it starts new everytime. And because of that its doing multiple dragzone.moveleft's every 10ms. How could I first just pause handler and then resume it when another dragevent starts?

Comment: So at onCreate I first do this `handler = new Handler(); `
And at ACTION_DRAG_STARTED I do this
        `b = true;
        handler.postDelayed(checkDragZone, 10);`
Then at ACTION_DROP
        `handler.removeCallbacks(checkDragZone);
        b = false;`

It seems working but is this correct way to use handler?

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a good practice to keep it running. You can start it when you detect the Drag action and then release it when it's finished.

Answer (score 0):

```
Runnable runnable;
Thread globalThread;

public void startThread() {
    if (threadController) {
        runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {


                while (threadController) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
                        final int value = i;

                        try {

                            Thread.sleep(4000);


                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                viewPager.setCurrentItem(value, true);
                            }
                        });
                    }

                }
            }
        };
        globalThread = new Thread(runnable);
        globalThread.start();
    } else {
        return;
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    threadController = false;

    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);


    runnable = null;

    if (globalThread != null) {
        globalThread.interrupt();
    }

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    threadController = false;
}
```

**Your resolve must be like this  globalThread.interrupt();**